# ng-class not properly working inside h1?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-class

I'm starting studying AngularJs and I was wondering why my code is not working? I was wondering why the `h1` tag is not getting orange with the `ng-class="'orange'"`.

I know that the answer could be quite easy but I'm just starting.

Here is my index.html:

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div ng-controller="MainController">
            <h1 ng-class="'orange'">Hello There</h1>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

})
```

P.s. no errors in the console.

Comment: You are using single quotes, you know the reason?

Comment: That I'm passing a string no? I tought that 'orange' was something defined by default, because actually in the video course that i'm following with this code it works.

Comment: seems to work here http://plnkr.co/edit/fsJtf6QRZJvDaiEcyRo3?p=preview

Comment: Without quotes angular would probably look for an orange property on the scope. But indeed it works in the plnkr posted.

Comment: @mrxd - You are right. So now, when you know what it mean, it should work for you as expected. Just inspect your code in console and you must be having class orange with your element. I do not see any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must work. Because as a resultant you are giving the class as direct `string` variable which value is `orange` with single quotes.

It is the same as that you are defining like scope variable which is returning value from as

```
<h1 ng-class="class">Hello There</h1>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.class='orange';
```

Both approaches are one as the same thing.

**Update**

You need to add css class to get those changes

```
<style type="text/css">
  .orange {
     color: orange;
  }
</style>
```

[**Demo  Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/IphZxhSyhelG43JiCITk?p=preview)

Comment: But it's still black, shouldn't it became orange?

Comment: @mrxd look at my edit..it should work now..you missed to add css clas

Comment: Aaaah so the ng-class goes to the css. I tought it was replacing the css.

 Ok thanks!

Comment: for that you need to use `ng-style` directive, it will set css properties on base of expression

Answer (score 1):

ng-class is used when you want to have a dynamic or scope related class, if you want to have a static class just use class.
I saw your comment, it does not replace any CSS by any means. its just a way to dynamically interchange css classes.

you can use it in several ways, such as:

```
<h1 ng-class="class">Hello There</h1>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.class='orange';
```

or with condiotions:

```
<h1 ng-class="{'danger' : condition}"><Hi</h1>
```

or tenaric if:

```
 <h1 ng-class=" condition? 'danger' : 'warning'">Hi</h1>
```

natuarlly condition is defined in the scope and the '' items are the classes to be added

Comment: my pleasure, anytime :)